# How change Gtk 3 code to pygtk 2.0

Tags: python, pygtk

How can I change this code from Gtk 3 to pygtk 2.0?

https://github.com/sebp/PyGObject-Tutorial/blob/master/examples/cellrenderertoggle_example.py

I have this part.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk

pygtk.require('2.0')

import gtk

class CellRendererToggle:

    def cell_toggled(self, widget, path):
        self.liststore[path][1] = not self.liststore[path][1]

    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window()
        window.set_default_size(200, 200)
        self.liststore = gtk.ListStore(str, bool, bool)
        self.liststore.append(["Debian", False, False])
        self.liststore.append(["OpenSuse", False, False])
        self.liststore.append(["Fedora", False, False])
        treeview = gtk.TreeView(model=self.liststore)
        cellrenderer_text = gtk.CellRendererText()
        column_text = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Text", cellrenderer_text, text=0)
        treeview.append_column(column_text)
        cellrenderer_toggle = gtk.CellRendererToggle()
        cellrenderer_toggle.connect("toggled", self.cell_toggled)
        column_toggle = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Toggle", cellrenderer_toggle, active=1)
        treeview.append_column(column_toggle)
        renderer_radio = gtk.CellRendererToggle()
        renderer_radio.set_radio(True)
        renderer_radio.connect("toggled", self.cell_radio_toggled)
        column_radio = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Radio", renderer_radio, active=2)
        treeview.append_column(column_radio)
        window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        window.add(treeview)
        window.show_all()

CellRendererToggle()

gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done that much with pygtk, but:

Easiest thing is probably to try running the code, and seeing where you get tracebacks.  Find one, fix one, find one, fix one.

There may well be a porting guide from 2.x to 3.x, but I doubt there's one for 3.x to 2.x.  However, looking at a 2.x to 3.x porting guide might help a little.